# How can I specify options in makeCluster in parallel or snow

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snow

I am using `parallel` or `snow` packages on Windows, the `makeCluster` function can take a `rscript` argument to specify where `Rscript` is for it to be executed on workers. What if I want it to be executed why `--vanilla` option ?

EDIT: running `makeCluster(2, rscript='pathToMyRScript --vanilla')` is not working on my box

Comment: I don't know this package and whether you can do what you want w/i the functions you are using, but if you run R from the command line you can certainly pass `--vanilla` and your script to it that way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a simple, direct method provided by those packages.  I would create a wrapper and specify the full path to that wrapper with the "rscript" option.  Theoretically that is easy, but practically you have to be careful when writing the wrapper to avoid errors due to reparsing the arguments in case they contain whitespace.  For example, I suspect that the following BAT script would have problems:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\Rscript" --vanilla %*
```

I would probably use a Python script using the subprocess module, but there are many possibilities to choose from, and you probably have your own favorite.

**Update**

As of R version 3.1.2, the `rscript_args` option was added to the `makeCluster` function. You can use this option to specify the `--vanilla` option:

```
makeCluster(2, rscript_args="--vanilla")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option is to either submit this as a feature request to the package authors, or dive into the function definitions and define your own calls to attempt generating the PSOCK nodes with Rscript called as `--vanilla`. See `parallel:::newPSOCKnode` and check how it defines the call to `Rscript`. The lines of interest are:

```
rscript <- if (getClusterOption("homogeneous", options)) {
    shQuote(getClusterOption("rscript", options))
}
else "Rscript"
cmd <- paste(rscript, "-e", shQuote(arg), env)
```

If you can modify the function to call `Rscript --vanilla` instead, it might work fine. I'm surprised that writing `rscript=<rscript_path> --vanilla` doesn't work though.

Comment: `rscript="Rscript --vanilla` doesn't work because the value of that option is quoted via the `shQuote` function, as shown in your answer.  Quoting is needed when the path contains whitespace, as it does when R is installed under "C:\Program Files", for example.

Answer (score 1):

From `An Introduction to R` on the R manual page, section B.4:

`If you just want to run a file foo.R of R commands, the recommended way is to use R CMD BATCH foo.R. If you want to run this in the background or as a batch job use OS-specific facilities to do so: for example in most shells on Unix-alike OSes R CMD BATCH foo.R & runs a background job.`

So in your case all commands have to go into the script, then you want

```
R --vanilla CMD BATCH your_script.R
```

From the command line, not the GUI.

Comment: Thanks but the question I ask is `parallel` specific, I know how to use `Rscript` in the common case